# Force Grouping of Notifications?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

According to the [Notification Design Guidelines](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) documentation:

*If the same app sends four or more notifications and does not specify a grouping, the system automatically groups them together.*

So I tested this out:
[image]

However, it only works when you have 4 or more notifications. I notice Messenger does this when you only have two notifications:
[image]

So my question is, can I tell the Android to always group my notifications like Messenger does? Or does Messenger use the `setGroup()` method that I would prefer not to use...

Comment: You said that you don't prefer `setGroup()`, why? And have you looked at the creating Style for your messages?

Comment: I am quite late into development, and to use the `setGroup()` method I would need to keep track of how many notifications I have shown. I would have to redo my whole notification system to implement this. I would think android could include a `setAutoBundle(true)` method

Comment: Did you figure out an answer to this maybe?

Comment: @William Nope :(

Comment: I am also looking for this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

It's doable.

The concept is to make a group notification builder for grouping up notifications and apply same `groupKey` to other notification builder. And call `NotificationManagerCompat.notify()` to build group notification beforehand. So these notifications with same `groupKey` will group together.

You can add group notification builder with `NotificationCompat.Builder.setGroup("GROUP_KEY")` and `NotificationCompat.Builder.setGroupSummary(true)`.

And add `NotificationCompat.Builder.setGroup("GROUP_KEY")` to other notifications.

```
val groupKey = "GROUP_KEY"

val groupBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "CHANNEL_ID")
groupBuilder.apply {
    setAutoCancel(true)
    ...
    setGroupSummary(true)
    setGroup(groupKey)
}

val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "CHANNEL_ID")
groupBuilder.apply {
    setAutoCancel(true)
    ...
    setGroup(groupKey)
}

val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, groupBuilder.build())
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_TAG, NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
```